# What's the intent behind this documentation?

Tags: java, string, exception, throw

In Java class [String method charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) there is an exception thrown at one case. The exception thrown is specified in documentation to be IndexOutOfBoundsException. The actual exception that is thrown is StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - a subclass of IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
/**
 * Returns the <code>char</code> value at the
 * specified index. An index ranges from <code>0</code> to
 * <code>length() - 1</code>. The first <code>char</code> value of the sequence
 * is at index <code>0</code>, the next at index <code>1</code>,
 * and so on, as for array indexing.
 *
 * <p>If the <code>char</code> value specified by the index is a
 * <a href="Character.html#unicode">surrogate</a>, the surrogate
 * value is returned.
 *
 * @param      index   the index of the <code>char</code> value.
 * @return     the <code>char</code> value at the specified index of this string.
 *             The first <code>char</code> value is at index <code>0</code>.
 * @exception  IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the <code>index</code>
 *             argument is negative or not less than the length of this
 *             string.
 */
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index + offset];
}
```

What is the intent to write in documentation IndexOutOfBoundsException instead of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ?

Comment: The latter is a subclass of the former, so both the documentation and the code are correct.  Been that way since JDK 1.0, according to the javadocs.

Comment: It conforms to the Liskov's Substitution Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, there are multiple `IndexOutOfBounds` exceptions (i.e, subtypes). Example - `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`, `StringIndexOutOfBounds`. They are all *Runtime Exceptions* (`IndexOutOfBoundsException` extends `RuntimeException`). They just follow the standard exception delegation model by calling `super()` because the Exception type is the same (`IndexOutOfBounds`). Hence the design.

They let the parent handle the Exception (gracefully) by passing custom messages.